# Python XML parsing with complicated structure (timestamp)

Tags: python, xml, parsing, parameters

How can I properly parse the follwoing xml codes?
I have tried a number of other examples codes, but they seem not work in my case.
Especially for the comma separated data structure.

This one might be simple:

```
   <parameter>
   <parameterName>Device.DMversion</parameterName>
   <parameterValue type="xs:string">02.00</parameterValue>
   </parameter>
```

But this one is a little bit complicated:

```
<parameter>
<parameterName>Device.LANDevice.1.WLANConfiguration.1.AssociationHistory.1.MACAddress</parameterName>
<parameterValue type="xs:string">aa:bb</parameterValue>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<parameterName>Device.LANDevice.1.WLANConfiguration.1.AssociationHistory.1.AssociationTime</parameterName>
<parameterValue type="xs:dateTime">2013-05-31T07:30:39-07:00</parameterValue>
</parameter>
```

A little more complicated:
Timestamp values are changing right after "ClientStats": 4-->5-->6
And I like to average parameterValues for all timestampes.

```
<parameter>
<parameterName>Device.LANDevice.1.WLANConfiguration.1.AssociatedDevice.1.ClientStats.4.CLIENT_STATS_Index</parameterName>
<parameterValue type="xs:unsignedInt">3</parameterValue>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<parameterName>Device.LANDevice.1.WLANConfiguration.1.AssociatedDevice.1.ClientStats.5.CLIENT_STATS_Index</parameterName>
<parameterValue type="xs:unsignedInt">3</parameterValue>
</parameter><parameter>
<parameterName>Device.LANDevice.1.WLANConfiguration.1.AssociatedDevice.1.ClientStats.6.CLIENT_STATS_Index</parameterName>
<parameterValue type="xs:unsignedInt">3</parameterValue>
</parameter>
```

Answer (score 1):

[Use a parser.](http://lxml.de/) Don't write your own code to do it, or you'll screw up all sorts of special cases you didn't think about or didn't realize existed.